# Showing option when page is frontpage

Tags: frontpage, options

Currently I'm having some difficulties with below snippet.

As it currently works it shows `the_excerpt_rss` on a single post and single page. AND it shows the option on `is_home()`.

But what if a page (instead of the 'blog') is the frontpage? If possible I'd like to include the option as well.

I've tried several versions of including `is_front_page()` but without any luck thus far.

The snippet I'm currently using:

```
<?php if (is_single() OR is_page()): if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>">
<?php endwhile; endif; elseif (is_home()): ?>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php $options = get_option('schema_theme_options'); echo $options['metadescription']; ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) {}`.

#### Edit

> but I've tried adding and replacing `<?php endwhile; endif; elseif (is_home()): ?>` with both of your code. Could you perhaps include your snippet with mine?

I'm not sure why you would do that. I was specifically answering this question:

> But what if a page (instead of the 'blog') is the frontpage? If possible I'd like to include the option as well.

The answer to that question is what I posted:

```
`if ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' )
```

**However**, that won't actually solve your problem, if I'm reading your code properly. Reading what you're asking, this *should* work:

```
if ( is_single() || is_page() || is_front_page() )
```

(Note: I used `||` instead of `OR` as the Boolean operator.)

To be honest, I'm somewhat surprised that this works on static pages. I didn't know that they generated RSS output.

Comment: if(get_the_ID() == get_option('show_on_front')) {}

Comment: @chip-bennett and @pippin, I'm probably a newb…, but I've tried adding and replacing `<?php endwhile; endif; elseif (is_home()): ?>` with both of your code. Could you perhaps include your snippet with mine?

Comment: @Pippin no; please see my comment to your answer. `show_on_front` returns either `page` or `posts`. You're thinking of `page_on_front`.

Comment: See updated answer...

Comment: Much appreciated! I've been using `the_excerpt_rss` for quite some time now for static pages, according to [this](http://www.nathanrice.net/blog/ultimate-guide-to-wordpress-seo-meta-descriptions/) guide by Nathan Rice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(get_the_ID() == get_option('show_on_front')) : ?>
     <meta name="description" content="<?php $options = get_option('schema_theme_options'); echo $options['metadescription']; ?>">
<?php elseif(is_single() OR is_page()) : ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
          <meta name="description" content="<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>">
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How's that?

Comment: I think you need **`get_the_ID() == get_option( 'page_on_front' )`**. The **`page_on_front`** option returns the ID of the static page set to display on the front page. The **`page_for_posts`** option returns the ID of the static page set to display the blog posts index. The **`show_on_front`** option returns either `page` or `posts`, depending on what the front page is set to display.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right.

Comment: Using `page_on_front` does indeed do the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I would be within the rules when adding this reply (I've been thinking about editing my original question instead)

First of all, @chip-bennett is right. I haven't been 100% clear when asking my question.
I wanted to use `the_excerpt_rss` for single posts and pages, and if the home page would show a static page or the posts page, I'd like to use the option.

Therefore, for future reference, this is the code I'm currently using:

```
<?php if (is_home() OR is_front_page()): ?>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php $options = get_option('schema_theme_options'); echo $options['metadescription']; ?>">
<?php elseif (is_single() OR is_page()): if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php the_excerpt_rss(); ?>">
<?php endwhile; endif; endif ?>
```